# Magento 2 : Error on running magento command

Tags: magento2, static-content, command-line, static-content-deploy

I'm new on Magento 2. (2.2.5, nginx, linux, MySQL 5.7.22, PHP 7.1.21) I was setting the configuration of store and when I refreshed the store page I get diamond question marks, also in admin console, I tried to clean and flush but I get several errors (I heard beeps in my console) and finally I get following error ;

> Fatal error: Class Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Indexer\Price\DefaultPrice'
>   not found in
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-bundle/Model/ResourceModel/Indexer/Price.php
>   on line 15

[image: command result]

[image: Chrome screen at the store home screen]

I've already delete delete pub/static/* and var/generation

(forgive my poor English)

Comment: Somebody help me plase !!